# Why is ErrorMessage in RequiredFieldValidator always displayed if it contains markup?

Tags: asp.net

I have encountered some odd behavior, and was hoping someone could shed some light on it. I've got a form laid out using tables (don't need the lecture on this, as its still the most consistent way to get a clean tabular layout in every single browser). I want a required field validator above one of my fields. If I put the validator in a row, it works fine. If I put the validator between rows, with the markup for the rows in the Text or ErrorMessage attribute, it is always displayed, no matter what. It was my understanding that the RequiredFieldValidator could contain markup in the ErrorMessage text, so I'm curious if anyone knows why this is happening.

This works fine:

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valNewCustPhone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtNewCustPhone" ErrorMessage="Please enter a contact phone number, including<br>area code and country code for non-US numbers." ValidationGroup="NewCustomer"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rightbold">Phone Number</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewCustPhone" MaxLength="25" Width="100"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will always display the ErrorMessage text on the page, even on initial page load, and even after a postback when the field contains data:

```
<table>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valNewCustPhone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtNewCustPhone" ErrorMessage="<tr><td colspan=2>Please enter a contact phone number, including<br>area code and country code for non-US numbers.</td><tr>" ValidationGroup="NewCustomer"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <tr>
        <td class="rightbold">Phone Number</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewCustPhone" MaxLength="25" Width="100"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. You are putting something outside the TR. which you should not do, it is not made for that. And if you look at the html you will see that the Validator generates a SPAN element in html.

Comment: Actually, with the markup in it, it is not generating a SPAN element at all, it is just rendering the <tr><td>message</td></tr> as specified in the error message. It is rendering the HTML correctly, just not at the right time.

Comment: But you are making a mess of the error message `ErrorMessage="<tr><td colspan=2>Please enter...` so it will give weird results. Better put the Validator inside the `<tr><td colspan=2>` and not make it a part of the message.

Comment: Possibly better, but not really my question. As I said, it renders just fine, rendering the row and cell tags exactly as specified in the message so it is rendered in place in the browser just fine. The question is why the BEHAVIOR changes when the ErrorMessage contains markup tags.

Comment: SImple, because it is not meant to. The browser reads the TD and TR in the ErrorMessage and tries to create a table.

Comment: I have edited my html snippets to include the <table> and </table> tags to make it more clear that that is exactly the behavior that I expect. Thought it would be obvious from what I had, but apparently not, so I'll be more explicit.